# Is this robots.txt making Google not to show some of my content?

Tags: robots.txt

http://chineselearnonline.com/

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /wp-

Sitemap: http://chineselearnonline.com/sitemap.xml
```

I just changed to a new server. And my site started to not to appear in the top search results s before. I was wondering if the robots.txt above is blocking some of my WordPress content?

**EDIT:**

I changed the path from `http://chineselearnonline.com/v4` to `http://chineselearnonline.com/` also, not sure if this is the real problem and no `robots.txt`

Comment: This is not a WordPress question.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170436/robot-txt-made-google-stop-indexing-my-site

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your site path, the urls previously indexed by search engines are no longer valid.

Google Webmaster Tools has a change of address tool: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83106

In general, you need to :

1. setup 301 redirects for your old urls
2. create a new sitemap
3. be patient

Answer (score 0):

You will need redirects, as is pointed out, but as for robots.txt, you're missing the allow line in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
```

And this line makes no sense `Disallow: /wp-` , so delete it.

Comment: There's no harm in adding `Allow: /`, but this statement is implied (everything is allowed by default except what is specifically excluded).